# What is the term for when a clause explains what preceded it?

Tags: terminology

I can't find out through google, because "explanation" of course just provides basic grammar lessons.

What is the term for a clause which explains a thought etc. preceding it?

So e.g.:

- I thought Jones was an idiot, **they behaved so strangely**

Comment: Note: You can't use the gender-neutral 'they' in this situation. Presumably you know whether Jones is male or female. You should use 'he' if Jones is male or  'she' if Jones is female. 'They' is only used when the individual is unspecified or unspecifiable.

Comment: @chasly An ideal example for the illustration of this point.

Answer (score 2):

If you change "they" to "he", as Chasly mentioned, and add "since" to connect your clause, you have the following sentence:

- I thought Jones was an idiot, since he behaved so strangely.

In that sentence, "he" is an **anaphora**, as it refers to an antecedent (in this case, Jones). A **cataphora** would refer to something that came later, or a postcedent.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, an entire clause can be considered postcedent or antecedent. In this case, everything after the comma is a postcedent clause.

Comment: thanks for the answer Lee. what about an explanation like: the idea passed, Jones was so tired. ? it seems like it contains no pro-form ?

Comment: I'm not sure how those two clauses are related, and they would have to be in order to use a pro-form (the umbrella term under which pronouns fall). None of the words in the first half can stand in for words in the second half of that sentence and vice-versa.

Comment: @user3293056 - Do you perhaps mean that the proposal passed because Jones was too tired to argue against it?

Comment: @aparente001 no i meant "idea", but it was an unusual expression, and i apologise

Comment: "idea" isn't enough of a clarification!  What do you mean by "passed" -- is there a vote going on?  What's the connection with Jones being tired?  Etc.